# Java 8 LocalDateTime to Date Lost Timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have this code and my system's default timezone is PDT. After the timezone conversion, finalDate shows time in PDT. How do I make it show the finalDate in "Asia/Singapore"?

```
String strDate = 201507081245;
DateTimeFormatter mx3DateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, format);
Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore")).toInstant();
Date finalDate = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: The java.time framework worked perfectly. The problem is your misunderstanding about how `java.util.Date` works. See the [correct Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158403/642706) by Codebender. To clarify for other readers, try to avoid using the old java.util.Date & .Calendar classes at all. The java.time classes supplant those old troublesome classes. In this Question’s code, there is no need for that last line converting from java.time to java.util.Date unless required for interoperating with some other code not yet aware of the new java.time types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object is not specific to a particular time zone. Yet its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method applies your JVM’s current default time zone.

You can ask it to print the time in a particular timezone with a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) such as [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Something like,

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hhhhMMddHHmm");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(finalDate));
```